Pagination in jetpack compose with retrofit query
If I have the following API response how can I achieve pagination in jetpack compose:
{"count": 42,
"next": "https://api.engaz-it.org/api/invoices/v1/?limit=10&offset=30",
"previous": "https://api.engaz-it.org/api/invoices/v1/?limit=10&offset=10",
"results": [
    {
        "id": 33,
        "created_by": "asem_adel",
        "created_at": "2024-07-24T22:29:06.897620Z",
        "modified_by": null,
        "modified_at": "2024-07-24T22:29:06.897646Z",
        "invoice_number": "2",
        "system_invoice_number": "20240724-6039fd8a",
        "client": "Gregory and Hughes LLC",
        "supplier": "Bailey",
        "driver": "kkk",
        "contractor": null,
        "status": "PENDING",
        "can_edit": true
    },....]}

I'm using mvvm architecture pattern.
